# How to write a CASE clause with another column as a condition using knex.js

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

So my code is like one below:

```
.select('id','units',knex.raw('case when units > 0 then cost else 0 end'))
```

but it gives me error like this one

> hint: "No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts."

Any idea how I should right my code so I can use another column as an condition for different to column ?

Comment: First is this mysql or postgres? Second, what data types are `units` and `cost`?

Comment: yeah it is postgres. Units are float8 and cost is string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't get the same error you do:

> CASE types integer and character varying cannot be matched

but regardless, the issue is that you're trying to compare apples and oranges. Postgres is quite strict on column types, so attempting to put an integer `0` and a string (value of `cost`) in the same column does not result in an implicit cast.

Turning your output into a string does the trick:

```
  .select(
    "id",
    "units",
    db.raw("CASE WHEN units > 0 THEN cost ELSE '0' END AS cost")
  )
```

Sample output:

```
[
  { id: 1, units: null, cost: '0' },
  { id: 2, units: 1.2, cost: '2.99' },
  { id: 3, units: 0.9, cost: '4.50' },
  { id: 4, units: 5, cost: '1.23' },
  { id: 5, units: 0, cost: '0' }
]
```

Comment: My man Rich Churcher back at it again! let me test and I will give feedback ASAP!

Comment: Thanks, Rich! I have been strugling with this code for whole day yesterday!

Comment: Another quick question is it possible to convert `cost` to integer ? I have tried to do it with CAST but it gives me **pg_atoi** error

Comment: I don't recommend converting to integer... unless maybe you're trying to store a total number of cents? Suggest a quick read of https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/datatype-money.html and https://knexjs.org/#Schema-specificType (which you'll need if you want to use Postgres' `money` type).

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion, my man! Yeah I was trying to store sum of units and cost therefore need it to be integer I used `cast` and it worked.